# how to set a taxonomy term active?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7

In my block i have different taxonomy term:
term A
-term B
--term c
---term D
when i am on term b it is set to active or bold if i am on term d then it is set to active and bold.
this is already been used
`$options = array();
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && arg(2) == $t->tid) {
    $options = array('attributes' => array('class' => 'active'));
}`

i am new in drupal anyone tell me how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The arg() function is taking argument parts from the url.
/taxonomy/term/2 means:
arg(0) = taxonomy
arg(1) = term
arg(2) = 2

Comment: yes it is taking from arg()